# After running npx react-native run-android app stuck in Starting: Intent {.../.MainActivity}

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

Hello have been trying to find a solution for this bug but haven't.
I have done a fresh install in my computer and trying to run a android studio project, everything worked fine and like a charm.

It even says:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 57s
474 actionable tasks: 474 executed
info Connecting to the development server...
8081
info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.app/.MainActivity }
```

The emulator turns on and it does nothing, nothing appears.
If I click directly on the app icon in the emulator it just closes and there's no error. Nowhere.

Have tried clean build
Erasing and creating another emulator
environment variables are fine.

Any help would be appreciated.